# Windows 8 drive somehow keyed to a computer?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, security, external-hard-drive, windows-8.1

Having an odd issue wherein I am working on a Windows 8 laptop and cannot access the hard drive after extraction and placement into an external enclosure that works.  I removed the drive to pull some data off of it, but when I put it into another machine (both a Mac OS X box and two Windows 8 machines), none of them will recognize the drive.

As noted, this enclosure works and other drives are fine on it; it is just this one Windows 8 drive that comes from HP and is factory default.  I thought perhaps it was the BIOS security settings for the drive (Secure Boot or some other options), but I disabled all of these.  All I can think is perhaps there is some encryption going on, even though I don't see the drive as being encrypted in Windows 8.

Any idea what may be going on here; particularly anything specific to Windows 8?

Comment: Is it Windows 8, or 8.1?  Which edition (Pro?)?

Comment: Windows 8.1.  Oddly it does not give any information about the Edition.

Comment: @ylluminate - If it does not say `Professional` or `Single Language` then its `Core` which simply means its not `Professional`. Single Language is a specific version of `Windows 8 Core` which only allows the installation of a single language pack.  Technically `Core` will not be referenced within Windows the official version is basically "not `Windows 8 Professional`"

Answer (score 1):

When you use a [Windows 8.1 device with an online account, the storage is encrypted with bitlocker](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/windows-8-1-includes-seamless-automatic-disk-encryption-if-your-pc-supports-it/).

So you need a Windows edition which supports accessing of bitlocker drives.